# Is there a a way to automatically swap a noise gate between two tracks based on relative volume?

Tags: mixing, post-production

I have two perfectly-aligned tracks, which came from two microphones in the same room, each having a person speaking in front of it. The problem is that the high frequencies of their audio have bled into each other and this tends to give it kind of a reverb effect where the room sounds more resonant than it actually is. If I only play one track at a time, the person who was at that mic sounds great.

The mics were plugged into the same mixer and have good alignment, but phase inversion has negligible effect (I suspect this is because the two tracks were recorded on different microphone models - this is a hand-me-down production).

I *think* the basic effect I'd like achieve is to always gate *exactly one* track at all times, but continually switch which track it's on so that it's always applying to whichever track was originally quieter. There are portions where the two tracks are fighting for dominance and if it bleeds during those portions then that's okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to give each track it’s own gate and set the threshold above the bleeding audio?

Alternatively, if you are so inclined, you can split the tracks during the non speaking sections and mute them/delete them

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, the bleed can exceed the quieter speaking in dB. This is why I wanted some kind of solution that takes into account both tracks together - no matter how loud it is, it should be gated if the other track is louder.

Yes, I can absolutely fix it by manually gating, but there's a lot of audio and I was hoping to save myself several hours with a good-enough automated solution.

Comment: Check for an automatic mic mixing (AMM) / Automixer plug-in.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a huge opportunity to find a solution. I didn't even know what to search for and now I have a plethora of articles and forum threads to comb through.